# Kenmore Pro Refrigerator Stuck in "0F" Mode

Tags: refrigerator

I have a Kenmore Pro Refrigerator (401.40483800, made by Samsung and similar to the Samsung [RS757LHQESR](https://www.manualslib.com/manual/2288816/Samsung-Rs757lhqesr-Series.html?page=53#manual)). The refrigerator is not cooling enough and the evaporator was a block of ice, so I tried to have the unit enter a manual diagnostic/defrost mode.

I pressed the Fridge Temperature and Freezer Temperature buttons for 6 seconds, based on reading instructions available for similar models online. The compressor stopped running and the fridge and freezer temperature displays changed to "0F", which I thought meant it was running a defrost cycle, but now I can't get it to return to normal operation.

I've turned the device off and on again several times, and pressed and held the fridge and freezer temperature buttons again (and many other combinations of panel button presses) to no avail - it is now completely unresponsive. What can I do to restore the refrigerator to operation?

Comment: you are in de-frost cycle, which is time controlled.

Comment: Is there any to force it to leave the de-frost cycle? Is the time likely to be more than an hour?

Comment: OF OF or O FF
Cooling Off Mode

Comment: Ah yep that seems like what is going on. Is that different from the defrost cycle, and do you have any ideas on how to get out of that mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**OF OF or O FF = Cooling Off Mode**

Locate the top two buttons on the left side of the panel. On newer models, the top button on the right side of the panel is also necessary. However, we recommend trying it with only 2 buttons first as you're less likely to be in Cooling Off Mode accidentally on models which require 3 buttons.
Simultaneously touch and hold these buttons for 5-8 seconds, until a chime sounds. This chime will sound different than when a single button is touched.
Wait a few moments to confirm that the display does not return to Cooling Off Mode status again. If it does, repeat these steps until you're successful.

Here is the list :[Samsung code](https://www.samsung.com/us/support/troubleshooting/TSG01003409/)

Comment: That was it, thank you so much! Is there a list of different modes and effects of various panel button combinations?